# Angular Webapp not opening in Safari, Iphone but working fine in google chrome and other browsers

Tags: angular, safari

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBe15.png)I have created an angular webapp, the webapp works fine when I open in Google chrome, but it doesn't load in safari in desktop and also it doesn't open in Iphones.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAAFM.png)

I have tried analysing the error in safari using inspect element, but I haven't understood what is causing this behaviour.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to debug minified code, which can be very hard. Is there a possibility that you can open the unminified application in a Safari browser? Hopefully this will lead you to the root of the error.